# Use Left outer join to remove duplicate row in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database table in mysql like this.

1).Tablestr .

```
     str_id       table_no    
        133         T1         
        156         T2         
        130         T3         
        143         T5         
        277         T6         
        28          T7
```

2). Booking table

```
   book_id       booked_by    str_id
        1          W          133
        2          P          277
        3          P          28,130
        4          P          156
        5          W          277
        6          W          143,156
        7          P          156,143
```

str_id is primary key  in tablestr table. str_id is foregin key in booking table which stores str_id comma separted values from tablestr table.

I want to Join this two table and produce the mysql output using some condition.

Condition involve in Query :

```
1). $cont1=Select str_id from bookingtable where booked_by="w".
2). Select * from Tablestr where str_id in ($cont1).
```

I want to select str_id from booking table where booked_by="w" then selected values need to be removed from tablestr.

So output i should get like this

```
     str_id       table_no    
        130         T3         
        28          T7
```

i can do this using Subquery. But it's takes 6 to 7 seconds where there is million data. can i use left join or some other query to perform this action very faster.

Comment: keeping comma separted values in relational database should be outlawed.

Comment: I have query to convert comma separated values to rows. that's no problem .

Comment: it is **defiantly a problem, *even if you are not aware of it.***

Comment: @Raj that *is* the problem. In Relational DB you store data relationally unless you have very good reasons.

Comment: mysql handles this well with find_in_set so not really an issue at the moment, but I have to agree with the other people here, either use an intermediary table or store seperate rows for each str_id, concatenating multiple values into one field for storage isn't recommended

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.str_id, t.table_no
from tablestr t
left join
booking b
ON find_in_set(t.str_id, b.str_id)
where b.booked_by = 'W';
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/386b6/3)

Edit: seeing as your ids are integers you can also use locate (probably even faster though I don't really know for sure)

```
select * from booking;
select t.str_id, t.table_no
from tablestr t
left join
booking b
ON locate(t.str_id, b.str_id)
where b.booked_by = 'W';
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/386b6/3)

find_in_set() is used to find a string in a list of strings
locate() is used to find an integer value in a list of integers

EDIT try running the subquery like this, not sure if it will be faster but have a look:

```
select str_id, table_no
from tablestr
where str_id not in
(select t.str_id
from tablestr t
left join
booking b
ON locate(t.str_id, b.str_id)
where b.booked_by = 'W');
```

EDIT: try using exists instead of IN, it might make the query faster:

```
select tstr.str_id, tstr.table_no
from tablestr tstr
where not exists
(select 1
from tablestr t
left join
booking b
ON locate(t.str_id, b.str_id)
where b.booked_by = 'W'
and tstr.str_id = t.str_id);
```

Comment: What you have posted will produce common values of both table.I need uncommon one. i have given sample output

Comment: ah, in that case I guess subquery is the only way to go

Comment: yes. i have subquery but it takes 6 seconds to produce output. Subquery is notoriously slow

Comment: @Raj try the query under my last EDIT, might be faster than your current one

Comment: @jermy c . My subquery and your subquery works in same speed . 6 to 7 Seconds.

Comment: alright, good to know for future reference, I guess that's as fast your query is going to get then

Comment: When there is 1000 records it takes 2 sec and when 5000 records it takes 6 to 7 seconds . What we can do ?

Comment: @Raj I added a new query in the end of my answer that uses EXISTS rather than IN I've read somewhere that it is faster